# Erase Volume Group PE Allocations

Tags: lvm

How can I erase the PE allocations on this VG so it is blank again? Currently there are only 18 free;

```
root@box1:~# vgdisplay 
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               tester
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  8
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               139.70 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              35762
  Alloc PE / Size       35744 / 139.62 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       18 / 72.00 MiB
  VG UUID               LJguxY-N8pM-wLE7-OOdB-ddI6-Q96M-gyNiFd
```

Comment: Do you mean how can you wipe the VG? presumably you have 139.62GB's worth of LVs, if you delete those (!) then you'll have more free. If you mean something else perhaps you could clarify?

Comment: Sorry yeah you are correct in your assumption. SO I presume I just need to use `lvremove` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, just use lvremove (carefully :) ) and it'll empty that VG ready for new LVs as needed.